# How to center align font awesome icons vertically in a circle div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center align font awesome icons center by  vertically. If there is text we can do it using `line-height` property even i tried giving the `line-height` same height as height of the div.

Tried `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` didn't do the trick.

How to center the icons vertically in all size. It should be dynamic because the icon size may differ. So a hardcode of margin-top may won't work for other size of icon as well div.

**CODE**

```
.exp{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100%;
    line-height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M3jxT/1/)

Comment: Add a new class to use on the icon itself:`.fa-center { line-height: inherit!important; vertical-align: middle; }`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use `line-height` to align the icon in the `div`.

Try adding this `.fa-camera-retro { line-height: inherit;}` to your css. Using `inherit` makes `line-height` take on the height of its containing div, so all icons will be centered even if those divs are different sizes. If you want, you  can also set the `line-height` to the div's height in pixels to explicitly center it, ie `line-height: 80px`
.

Here's the example working in a <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/M3jxT/2/)</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. I thought i should give the `line-height` to the containing div. but now only am get to know that i should give it to the child(.fa-camera-retro) too

Answer (score 28):

Not to detract from the above solution which functions perfectly, but Font Awesome has a great inbuilt stacking feature that can be used with the following code:

**FontAwesome 4x**

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Full documentation and working examples can be [found here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#stacked).

**FontAwesome 5x**

FontAwesome 5 works in exactly the same way. Just need to adjust the FontAwesome icons to match the new classes for different styles.

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Full documentation and working examples can be [found here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons).

Comment: This is the right answer. Do use put custom style when not needed.

Comment: How do you resize them?

Comment: They're just custom fonts so the size can be changed with `font-size`. They're based on `em` values so they should remain consistently spaced and aligned.

Comment: Link no longer exists, so this answer is hard to utilize.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the archived documentation for v4 as well as an example and documentation for v5

Answer (score 8):

Set a class for font awesome 
such as  .fa-vc
then add it to all font awesome font you want it to be aligned with other text. 
your code will looks like(this sample is a 'x' sign)

```
<i class="fa fa-times fa-vc"></i>
```

and 
set this class to

```
.fa-vc{line-height:inherit!important;}
```

this will override font awesome's default setting (line-height:1px)

problem solved...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a mixin I like to use for general vertical alignment:

```
@mixin vertical-align($position: relative) {
  position: $position;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@include vertical-align;
```

Works beautifully if you're using Boostrap as well, use a `center-block` class and it's perfectly centered.

Comment: This css works very well as no px units need to me declared. No matter what the content size or container the icon will be vertically center...I think some people saw your code maybe some did not understand this was sass...you should always answer assuming people don't know...after all its the reason we all come here. For future readers just take the css          `position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);` and apply to a class or your element and adjust it accordingly. This should be the answer @Gothburz you should update your answer with just plane jane css

Answer (score 2):

`vertical-align: middle` will work if you set the `div` `display: table-cell`
http://jsfiddle.net/M3jxT/484/

Comment: This seems to work better as accepted answer at least for fa-minus,  +1

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked +4 years ago and technology and browser compatibility has changed quite a lot. Another, more modern approach is use of Flexbox. It's scaleable and you can style a single element instead of styling the parent element and the child element.

What is wonderful about this approach is if you update the width or height, it will automatically with out updating anything else stay vertically and horizontally center.

**Pros:** It works with a single font-icon no problem

**Cons:** If you want to use a font-icon plus text like, "download" you will need to remove the "width" and it will still work as intended

**Example:**

```
.exp {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/iandonahue/M3jxT/1409/

Answer (score 1):

the equal line-height and text-align: center works very well to make icon in the middle both vertically and horizontally. However, if you want to make anything centered both vertically and horizontally in a dynamic way, code like this -

markup:

```
<div class="container>
   <div class="target">
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
   position: relative;
}

.target{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem to vertical aligning a font awesome icon in chrome and Mozilla.

I had a div wrapping my font awesome element.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="icon-wrap">
    <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
</div>
```

giving font size in **em** solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Using the fa-fw class makes them correctly aligned.

```
<div class="col-sm-1"> 
    <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-fw"></i>
</div>
```

Check it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/ahj0ncpa/

Comment: this is horizontal, the question is vertical