# center align icon in circle/disc

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, I have a display that places an icon in a circle/disc.

Here is an example of what I have:

[image]

But I am struggling at placing the icon in the center of the circle/disc.

I have searched SO (found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832226/how-to-center-align-font-awesome-icons-vertically-in-a-circle-div) but changing the line-height only expands the disc/circle) & Google, looked at plenty of examples, but I cannot configure my CSS class code to center the icon.

Hoping that someone can suggest an answer.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 padding-bottom-10 visual_preview_standard" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; background-color: silver;">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="circle_icon" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
          <icon class="fa fa-graduation-cap" style="font-size: 70px;"></icon>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <b>University Name</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS class:

```
span.circle_icon {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8em;
    box-shadow:  0 0 0 6px #000;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 10em
}
```

Comment: you can use `position:relative; top://desired px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use

```
icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```css
span.circle_icon {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8em;
    box-shadow:  0 0 0 6px #000;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 10em
}
icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4 padding-bottom-10 visual_preview_standard" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; background-color: silver;">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="circle_icon" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
          <icon class="fa fa-graduation-cap" style="font-size: 70px;"></icon>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <b>University Name</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your icon height, the best way to do it is:

```
span.circle_icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px; /*if the icon is, for example, 40px in height.
    - (half of icon height) */
}
```

And `position: relative;` for the container;