# How to use FontAwesome stacked icons as href attribute

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

In my `index.html` file I'm using stacked font-awesome icons as href buttons inside the table cell, like so:

```
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Details" style="vertical-align: top;">
              <span class="fa-stack">
                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-info fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit" style="vertical-align: top;">
              <span class="fa-stack">
                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" style="vertical-align: top;">
              <span class="fa-stack">
                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
```

However, the `fa-circle` icons seem to be not in line with the inner icon. It can be clearly visible on the figure here:

[image]

I've read that  `<span class="fa-stack">` should do the trick, but in my case, it doesn't quite work. What may be the easiest way to correct the misalignment?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832226/how-to-center-align-font-awesome-icons-vertically-in-a-circle-div

Comment: Thank you @Infa for a hint. I've already seen that one and unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. The thing is, when I ctrl + refresh the site, the icons seem to display the way I want them to be, but after a split of a second they resize to the ones I've shown on the picture above.

Comment: Put the css code in the ask and maybe can help you :)

Comment: I've finally dealt with the problem. Just added `data-auto-replace-svg= "false"` configuration attribute in script import, like described [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/configuration). The `<i>` tags were replaced with `<svg>` by default.